# QBD Query by Customer Name (DevKit)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I think this has been asked before, but I'm going to give it another shot in the hope of getting a useful answer.

Using the DevKit and C# (not XML) how can I look up a customer by name? In the SDK it was a no-brainer to look up a customer by FullName, but now I can't find any way to do it. It defies common sense that the DevKit wouldn't provide a way to do this.

Please don't reply with links to documentation that doesn't have the answer (I've read it several times), or XML that doesn't work. I'd love to see C# code that does this (heck, I'll even settle for VB), but if it can't be done, please just tell me so I can end this and get some rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var qbdCustomerQuery1 = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
qbdCustomerQuery1.Item1ElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item1ChoiceType.FirstLastInside;                             qbdCustomerQuery1.Item1 = "Popeye";

List CustomerQueryResult = qbdCustomerQuery1.ExecuteQuery(context).ToList();

This should work.

We will try to improve the docs for such queries.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need. Yes, the doc isn't very intuitive, especially all those "item" fields. I'll verify this answer as soon as IPP and the developer site are back online. Extremely slow and/or non-functional right now. openid.intuit.com timed out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give it a try

```
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, appToken, realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBD)
CustomerQuery customerQuery = new CustomerQuery();
customerQuery.FirstLastName ="?"
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = customerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(context);
```

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/query_filters/quickbooks_desktop

In the client side, you can loop through 'customers' and use an if condition for only customer's name.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I must be missing something. If I have 50,000 customers in QB Enterprise, uniquely identified by name (FullName), I'm not going to bring all 50,000 customers across the wire just to find 1 name.